# How to make a friend finder app in phonegap?

Tags: html, web-applications, cordova, google-maps-markers, google-maps-mobile

i am building a Phonegap app that should also work as a friend finder... Meaning, that you want to get coordinates from a friend using the same app and pinpoint (or watch) his current location on your (google) maps.

Google has an interesting service called Google Latitude, but i haven't found any info on how to integrate it in to a Phonegap app...
http://www.google.com/mobile/latitude/

Any info regarding this will be much appreciated,

regards Jasha

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look through the API for Latitude.

https://developers.google.com/latitude/